# Twitter Bootstrap and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded "bootstrap.js", and put in in my assets/javascript directory and I have put this in my rails view:

new.html.erb

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

which is the same code exactly as in the twitter guide.
When I reload the page the modal is there, and doesn't work at all, and when I press the button no animation is shown, the modal just pops up! any suggestion to make it work?

also where do I put the JS code like this one?

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/assets/javascripts/application.js`.

Does it include this line?

```
//= require_tree .
```

Or any line required for boostraps.

Answer (score 0):

Include `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and `jquery-rails` Gems in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

then run:

```
bundle install
```

then run:

```
rails generate bootstrap:install
```

This is should take care where to load bootstrap and jQuery. As for your own JavaScript code put it inside `filename.js` in `/assets/javascripts/`